# Can I query a field inside nested Document in firestore?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a structure like :

```
[Collection] users
     [Document] id
          [Collection] public
               [Document] data
                    [Field] isArtist: boolean
                    [Field] name: string
          [Collection] private
               [Document] data
                    //...some fields
     [Document] id
          [Collection] public
               [Document] data
                    [Field] isArtist: boolean
                    [Field] name: string
          [Collection] private
               [Document] data
                    //...some fields
```

Now I wanna query all users with

```
{
     isArtist : true,
     name: "something"
}
```

I don't really see anything helpful for this case in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [collection group queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).  Something like this should work:

```
const query = db.collectionGroup('public')
  .where('name', '==', 'something')
  .where('isArtist', '==', true);

let matches = [];

query.get().then((snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    matches.push({id: doc.id, ...(doc.data())});
  });
});
```